# Android - Why this TextView is moving its position after changing its visibility programmatically?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, visibility, visibilitychange

Initially both `TextViews` are visible and aligned correctly:

[image: Both TextViews are visible.]

After clicking the `Button`, I set both `TextViews` visibility to `GONE`. Second time I click on the `Button`, I set the visibility again to `VISIBLE`, but the result is the below:

[image: Result after changing the visibility to GONE and back to VISIBLE.]

Next times changing the visibility, I always get the same result.

How can I solve this to get always the appearance of the first image?

Thank you!

Layout:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/iconos_futbolista"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/posicion_tv"
            style="@style/IconosPerfilTextView"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/green"
            android:text="@string/pos_medio" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/seleccion_sub_fut_tv"
            style="@style/IconosPerfilTextView"
            android:alpha="0.15"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/claret"
            android:text="@string/internacional_sub" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/boton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cambiar"/>
    
</LinearLayout>
```

Style:

```
<style name="IconosPerfilTextView" >
    <item name="android:layout_width">64dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">64dp</item>
    <item name="android:autoSizeTextType">uniform</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/perfil_iconos_background</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-condensed</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:padding">4dp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I can't really explain why it lays out that way at the start, but it's apparently aligning the `TextView`s' baselines after you re-show it, which is `LinearLayout`'s default behavior. Add `android:baselineAligned="false"` to the opening `iconos_futbolista` `<LinearLayout>` tag.

Comment: Hi @mike-m, your solution, worked even if you don't know why this is happening. Thank you so much!